# How to Run standford corenlp server on Google Colab?

Tags: stanford-nlp, google-colaboratory

I want to use stanford corenlp for obtaining dependency parser of sentences. In order to using stanford corenlp in python, we need to do the below steps in Google Colab:

1. Install java

> import os
>
> !apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null
>
> os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"

2. Download stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05 and extract it.

> !wget http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05.zip
>
> !unzip stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05.zip

3. Change directory to stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05 folder with "cd" command.
4. Run this command in the current directory:

> "java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer
>   -port 9001 -timeout 75000"

After that, stanford-corenlp server will run at 'http://localhost:9001'

When I attempt to follow the answer on the post @ 
[how to run stanford corenlp server on google colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56001048/how-to-run-stanford-corenlp-server-on-google-colab) 
I end up getting the response:

---

Port 9001 is closed, retrying...

Port 9001 is closed, retrying...

Port 9001 is closed, retrying...

Port 9001 is closed, retrying...

---

Is there any other technique or tutorial known where I may connect between two different google colab .ipynb?

Comment: As of 2021-07-31 the Notebook you provided ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56001048/how-to-run-stanford-corenlp-server-on-google-colab ) runs perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

## Took a page out of tensor board playbook.

### Run standford core in the background

```
LOGDIR = '/tmp/log'
get_ipython().system_raw(
    'java -mx8g -cp "*" 
    edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9001 ->timeout 60000 &'
    .format(LOGDIR)
)
```

### Use ngrok to tunnel traffic to localhost

```
! wget https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip
! unzip ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip
```

```
get_ipython().system_raw('./ngrok http 9001 &')
```

### Retrieve public url

```
! curl -s http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels | python3 -c \
    "import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)['tunnels'][0]['public_url'])"
```

### Take returned url from above and update the PyCoreNLP.py default_url

URL_DEFAULT = "http://localhost:9000" <- replace URL from above here
Save the file...
then run the server in the background locally on Google Colab

Comment: need to change port from 9000 or 9001 to a higher number, 9000 is used by Google Colab