# Sentiment Analysis Stanford NLP in Google Colab

Tags: stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

Please, I'm trying to use sentiment analysis using Stanford NLP on Google Colab, but I dont know how to 'redirect' the server, as explained here:

[How to Run standford corenlp server on Google Colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59193589/how-to-run-standford-corenlp-server-on-google-colab)

I don't know about servers in generally. I would like to do this in Colab:
To do this,this code worked in my computer:

1-I've downloaded the Stanford NLP library;

2-The files containing the text that I want to process with sentiment analysis are in a folder ( what I've call as "directory_path"(input) in the above code);

3- I want to generate(output) a xml file with the output/answer generated by the server

```
import os
from pycorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP

nlp = StanfordCoreNLP('http://localhost:9000')


#above is the directory with files that contains the content (text) I want to process with Stanford NLP:
directory_path = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\ic\\Reviews\\reviews HetRec\\Hetrec_reviews\\Separated Reviews\\Separated Reviews"


for file in os.listdir(directory_path):

    current_file = os.path.join(directory_path, file)

    review_text = ""
    with open(current_file, encoding='utf8') as f: 
        res = f.readlines() 
        review_text += "".join(res)
        #review_text is a string representing the content read in the file.



    res = nlp.annotate(review_text,
                    properties={
                        'annotators': 'sentiment',
                        'outputFormat': 'xml',
                        'timeout': 50000,
                    })

    #above, file_name is just a generic name for the xml files I want to generate:
    file_name = file[0 : -3] + "xml"

   #get the output generated by the server:
    with open(file_name, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        print(res, file=f)
```

Any advice can help me! So, my objective is just generate the output using this code on Google Colab - but this code doesn't work on Colab, and I know nothing about servers and don't have much experience .I didn't find working examples of code for sentiment analisys with Stanford NLP in Colab.

Note: as far as I know, Stanza library doesn't support sentiment analysis. I don't mind about the version of the library used - it can be older version of Stanford NLP too.

Comment: Are you open to a pure python approach? You could try Vader or textblob?

Comment: I need to use strictly Stanford NLP...